# How change the swipe direction in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, swipe

I'm trying to put the swipe in two directions (left and right), but no matter what I do the swipe, the page always pops from right to left. How do I do that, in case I swipe from left to right the page appears from the left and if I make the right, page appears from the right?

This is my code:

**page.html:**

```
<ion-content class="home_content" (swipe)="swipe($event)" padding>
</ion-content>
```

**page.ts**

```
swipe(event) {
    if(event.direction == '2') {
      this.navCtrl.push(Page1);
    }
    if(event.direction == '4') {
      this.navCtrl.push(Page2);
    }
  }
}
```

The code works and push to the two pages, but they appears from te same side(right side).

Comment: Did you tried [Ionic Slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) ?

Comment: Ionic slides don't work for pushing to others pages, just for content in the same page